# Getting error 502/504 when trying to get InputStream

Tags: java, http, get

```
URL queryUrl = new URL(url);
InputStream inputStream = null;
HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection) queryUrl.openConnection();
connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "My Client");
connection.setRequestMethod("GET"); 
connection.setDoInput(true);
inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
```

Hi,
I'm using the above code to perform an HttpGet query.
I'm getting once in a few tries an exception that server returned error code 502 or 504 (both scenarios occur).
The exception is thrown in the line :

```
inputStream = connection.getInputStream()
```

Any ideas?

Your help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Comment: what type exception?  What are the server logs saying?

Comment: would you post the error StackTrace!

Comment: Server returned HTTP response code: 504 for URL: ....... 
sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source) 
sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(Unknown Source) 
Utils.queryGET(BtcE.java:330)

Answer (score 1):

The error code in 5xx indicates some issue with Server or proxy. Rfc Statement

```
Response status codes beginning with the digit "5" indicate cases in which the server is 
aware that it has erred or is incapable of performing the request. Except when responding 
to a HEAD request, the server SHOULD include an entity containing an explanation of the 
error situation, and whether it is a temporary or permanent condition. User agents SHOULD
display any included entity to the user. These response codes are applicable to any request method.
```

Please check what is the actual error by reading the error steam of url connection as below:
If the HTTP response code is 4nn (Client Error) or 5nn (Server Error), then you may want to read the HttpURLConnection#getErrorStream() to see if the server has sent any useful error information.

```
InputStream error = ((HttpURLConnection) connection).getErrorStream();
```

Also I think for working with http requests, you can use Apache HttpClient instead of directly working with HttpUrlConnection. Using HttpClient is lot more easier.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I will add errorCode output to my code and will try to analyse.   In the meanwhile - is there something wrong I'm doing there which can cause exceptions?

Comment: Since the error is with status code 5xx, i doubt any issues from client(your) end. Please check web server logs and also proxy logs for any clues during the time you have received 5xx response.